# Ruby on Rails number_field default value not displaying

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The default value for my text field is displaying as it should, but the number field is blank.

```
 <%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :nick_name, "Nickname: " %> (optional)
  <%= f.text_field :nick_name, class: 'form-control', value: "newgame" %>

  <%= f.label :players, "Number of players:" %> (3-8)
  <%= f.number_field :players, class: 'form-control', value:3 %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Game", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The value shows in the resulting source html, but is not displayed:

```
  <label for="game_nick_name">Nickname: </label> (optional)
  <input class="form-control" value="newgame" type="text" name="game[nick_name]" id="game_nick_name" />

  <label for="game_players">Number of players:</label> (3-8)
  <input class="form-control" value="3" type="number" name="game[players]" id="game_players" />
```

I tried `value: '3'` and that doesn't make a difference. 
To test if it was a problem with my browser, I made a simple html file on it own with a input field:

```
<input type='number' class='form-control' value=3>
```

It display as expected, so I think it must be something with my rails app.

I don't know if this is related at all to [Input value doesn't display. How is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772124/input-value-doesnt-display-how-is-that-possible), as this is a rails app.

Comment: value should come from the record itself if previously set. you shouldn't set `value` attribute manually. If its a `new` record you are trying to create then `value` should be empty and If you are trying to edit the previous record then it will show up by default.

Comment: yes in this way for new game object it will not shown a default value, in controller when you are initializing it you can set a value in it @game = Game.new(players: 3....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes in this way for new game object it will not show a default value, in controller when you are initializing it you can set a value in it

```
@game = Game.new(players: 3)
```